# Parsing json string number losing minimum precision

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, string-parsing

i'm working in a C# (Unity3D compatible = .NET 2.0) Json library and i'm having precision problems. Firstly i have this logic in order to parse number strings:

```
...
string jsonPart ="-1.7555215491128452E-19"
enter code here
long longValue = 0;
if (long.TryParse(jsonPart, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out longValue))
{
    if (longValue > int.MaxValue || longValue < int.MinValue)
    {
        jsonPartValue = new JsonBasic(longValue);
    }
    else
    {
        jsonPartValue = new JsonBasic((int)longValue);
    }
}
else
{
    decimal decimalValue = 0;
    if (decimal.TryParse(jsonPart, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out decimalValue))
    {
        jsonPartValue = new JsonBasic(decimalValue);
    }
}
...
```

The problem comes because decimal type is not the best type always for big decimal numbers. I have an output log to show you the problem (using .ToString()):

```
String = "-1.7555215491128452E-19"
Float Parsed : -1.755522E-19
Double parsed : -1.75552154911285E-19
Decimal Parsed : -0.0000000000000000001755521549
```

but on the other way , this examples with decimal type is the right one:

```
String = "0.1666666666666666666"
Float Parsed : 0.1666667
Double parsed : 0.166666666666667
Decimal Parsed : 0.1666666666666666666

String = "-1.30142114406914976E17"
Float Parsed : -1.301421E+17
Double parsed : -1.30142114406915E+17
Decimal Parsed : -130142114406914976
```

I suppost there is many other cases that can balance to one type or another. 
Is there any smart way to parse it loosing minimum precision?

Comment: The `int` type expects integers (= without decimal part) and thus will always fail when parsing the values you are referring (e.g., 0.166). This has nothing to do with the precision, but with parsing an invalid numeric format. For "0."+ whatever never use `int` or `long`.

Comment: The int is not the problem . This is a generic test , and has nothing to do with ints . The problem comes with decimal part and the types double vs decimal. I will remove int and long parse examples to avoid confusions.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment. In the future, please don't include so misleading information in your post. In any case, what is the problem then? you have parsed a value beyond the decimal range and thus parsing to decimal delivers something wrong? This is logical: you cannot use a type outside its min/max values. Why your code accounts for the int eventuality ( if (longValue > int.MaxValue), but it doesn't account for the decimal one? Same story than with int/long. If decimal value is too big, use double.

Comment: Floating point precision is not perfect. But equivalent issues happen in all the languages. The question is: you seriously need to deal with over 10^19 values? In extreme situations, you might consider BigInteger (although I am pretty sure that you might avoid such situations in many different ways). But accounting for over 10 decimal positions? For what? The limits are there for a perfectly logical reason: going so far is not required. Write sensible code and keep away from in-the-boundaries situations (this is an advice that works in almost any context).

Comment: I understand your answer but there is no BigInteger in .NET 2.0 . And the decimal problem is not about min or max values , but precision places.

Comment: As said, anything beyond 10 decimal positions is certainly redundant in almost any situation (the algorithm/logic might be done such that anything beyond that doesn't matter) and `decimal` type can take care of 10 positions (and more) without any problem.

Comment: In this specific case, parsing strings which might take extremely long values, you should do a (simple & quick) pre-analysis. Count the number of digits & decimal positions, reduce the length if required and parse it to the most adequate type. Perfectly working solution for any possible scenario.

Comment: i must count with exponencial notation too, but be sure this must the the path to solve the problem.

Comment: Do it too. It would be a quite straightforward analysis anyway: `Split` for "." and "e" (`input.ToLower()`); both parts to `long` (I guess that you can safely assume that any of the parts before/after "." or "e" will never be greater than `long`) and a set of conditions deciding what to do. Or better: you might perform the whole analysis by treating it as `string`s and making decisions on account of the lengths of the parts.

Answer (score 1):

The difference you are seeing is because, although `decimal` can hold up to 28 or 29 digits of precision compared to double's 15 or 16 digits, its range is much lower than `double`.

[A decimal has a range of (-7.9 x 10^28 to 7.9 x 10^28) / (10^(0 to 28))](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx)

A `decimal` stores ALL the digits, including zeros after a decimal point which is preceeded by a zero (e.g. 0.00000001) - i.e. it doesn't store numbers using exponential format.

[A double has a range of ±5.0 × 10^−324 to ±1.7 × 10^308](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx)

A `double` can store a number using exponential format which means it doesn't have to store the leading zeroes in a number like 0.0000001.

The consequence of this is that for numbers that are at the edges of the decimal range, it actually has less precision than a double.

For example, consider the number `-1.7555215491128452E-19`:

Converting that to non-exponential notation you get:

```
-0.00000000000000000017555215491128452
            1         2         3
   12345678901234567890123456789012345
```

You can see that the number of decimal digits of that is 35, which exceeds the range of a `decimal`.

As you have observed, when you print that number out after storing it in a `decimal`, you get:

```
-0.0000000000000000001755521549
           1         2         
   1234567901234567890123456789
```

which is giving you only 29 digits, as per Microsoft's specification.

A `double`, however, stores its numbers using exponential notation which means that it doesn't store all the leading zeroes, which allows it to store that particular number with greater precision.

For example, a `double` stores  `-0.00000000000000000017555215491128452` as an exponential number with 15 or 16 digits of precision.

If you take 15 digits of precision from the above number you get:

```
-0.000000000000000000175552154911285
                              1
                     123456789012345
```

which is indeed what is printed out if you do this:

```
double d = -1.7555215491128452E-19;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("F35"));
```

Comment: Great i understand now what is suspect, but, Is there any smart solution to select the type that it must be converted?

Comment: @A.Quiroga Since you're writing a Unity program and not a financial application, I can't see any reason to use anything other than `double`.

Comment: I'm going to make it opensource and i always try to do the best effort to have a better library. Maybe i'm not doing a financial application but others do. Anyway thanks for the explanation.